# Does each gate have one, or two matrices in LSTM?

Tags: lstm

According to these equations in wikimedia:

[image: LSTM equations from wikimedia]

each gate has **two** weight matrices:***W,U*** respectively,but according this:
[image: forget gate equation]
from:http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

each gate has **only one** weight matrix:***W***,and in the example code:

```
z = np.row_stack((h_prev, x))
f = sigmoid(np.dot(W_f, z) + b_f)
i = sigmoid(np.dot(W_i, z) + b_i)
```

from:http://blog.varunajayasiri.com/numpy_lstm.html,apparently:

```
input and previous hidden status are stacked together to multiply same weight matrix
```

So,

1. **Does each gate have one, or two matrices in LSTM?**
   or I don't understand them correctly
2. if two,what does **U** matrix(wikimedia) mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area the same thing.

$W\cdot [a; b] = U\cdot a + V\cdot b$
if  $W=[U\; V]$

For $[a;b]$ being the vertical concatenation of the vectors (considered as column matrices) 
and  $[U\; V]$ the horizontal concatenation of the  matrices respectively.

The difference is purely notation.

Consider [how matrix multiplication works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).
or we are looking at it [as a block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication)

$$[U\; V]\cdot [a;b] =  U\cdot a + V\cdot b $$

Comment: ,thanks,so the example is wrong?

Comment: No, both are correct. They are just two different ways of  writing the same thing. They are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: so wikimeida cuts a tall weight matrix to two short matrices?

Comment: Exactly. (or equivalently colah stacks to short matrices into one tall one)